# Postgresql: Querying on a list of pairs where one field is a fuzzy match and another exact

Tags: postgresql

I want to query multiple addresses based on the `street name` and `city`. The street name is a fuzzy match whereas city is an exact. If we are querying a single record, the following works:

```
SELECT
    *
FROM
    Addresses a
WHERE
    a.street like '32 foxrun%' --could be foxrun st or foxrun street
AND
    a.city = 'Montreal'
```

### Problem

I would like to run the above query on thousands of street name/city pairs. I know I can use

`LIKE ANY('{32 foxrun%, 45 main%}')`

to match the street names, but since there are likely quite a few main streets, it helps to add the additional address component, city. Furthermore, I know I could break up the WHERE clause into an OR for each city, like so:

```
WHERE
    (a.street LIKE ANY('{32 foxrun%, 45 main%}') and a.city = 'Montreal')
OR
    (a.street LIKE ANY('{74 broad%, 2 kings%}') and a.city = 'Los Angeles')
```

But since the number of cities can be in the thousands, I was hoping there was a more effective solution.

Thank you!

Comment: Also, if anyone can think of a better title for this question...

Comment: Are the thousands of pairs in a table?  Can you put them into a values list?  If I had thousands of pairs in a data structure in a client language (python, perl, etc.), I would just loop over them and execute the query once for each pair.

Comment: @jjanes - that is what we are currently doing. But as you know, having a query within the loop is terribly inefficient. Better even to just pull all records in those cities and then filter in code. My thought was if we could capture it in a single query, it would be far more efficient. But practically we solved (for now) by following your suggestion.

Comment: Query in a loop is usually not all that inefficient if you have the right indexes.  If I already had the data in a table, I would certainly do a join, but I usually wouldn't bother to create and stuff it into a table just on efficiency grounds.  (Unless doing it all at once would use a Hash Join or Merge Join, but LIKE queries are indexable but are not hashable or mergeable.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a join against a `values` clause:

```
select a.*
from addresses a
join (
  values 
    ('32 foxrun%', 'Montreal'), 
    ('42 answer%', 'London'), 
    .... more parameters ...
) as t(street, city) on a.city = t.city and a.street like t.street;
```